# How do I boot from /dev/sdb1 rather than /dev/sda

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, manjaro, gparted

I have a manjaro partition that I would like to install on my computer. I have it mounted on /dev/sdb1 with the boot and esp flags. However, my computer only recognizes the /dev/sda1 partition, which contains my Solus OS installation. How do I set my UEFI bootsystem to boot from /dev/sdb1?

Comment: If I understand correctly you have a dual boot consisted of Manjaro and Solus. If that's the case do you have GRUB installed?

Comment: No, I don't have GRUB installed, but I didn't need to install Grub to get Solus on my system so I figured it would be the same for Manjaro. By the way, I don't have Manjaro on my system I just have a partition (/dev/sdb1) that has a bootable partition for it.

Comment: I see. Know that dual booting typically requires a boot loader like GRUB. As for your problem, what's the brand of your laptop or motherboard (PC)?

Comment: Dell Latitude E7440. Not sure how this would affect my problem, but ill also try setting up GRUB I guess.

Comment: You can try changing it in BIOS.

Alternatively try using efibootmgr https://superuser.com/questions/936430/how-can-an-os-change-the-boot-order

Comment: Maybe you have grub even if you don't know it. I would guess that when you installed Solus, you also installed the grub bootloader. Anyway, when booted into Solus (and your /dev/sdb drive is connected) , please try the following command line: `sudo update-grub` from a terminal window, and reboot. It might bring you a grub menu with a menu entry for Manjaro.

Comment: Hi @sudodus, unfortunately I get an error when trying that command.

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `LiveOS_rootfs'.

Comment: Are you running Solus as a live system (as opposed to an installed system)? Or is some USB drive or memory card with a live system connected, when you run `sudo update-grub`? -- Is the Manjaro system that we talk about a live system or an installed system?

Comment: I'm running Solus as a live system. Unfortunately I cannot install it and I won't mention why as that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: That explains why `sudo update-grub` does not work (when run in Solus). What about Manjaro. Is it installed or also a live system? How did you install it (into /dev/sdb1)? What tool/method did you use?

Comment: Ok so I simply installed the iso via Firefox and a mirror, then I used the command "dd if=Manjaro.iso of=/dev/sdb1"

Comment: A system, that is cloned from an iso file is a live system, and it should be cloned starting at the head of the drive (not into a partition). So try cloning it to **`/dev/sdb`** (instead of  `/dev/sdb1)`. Then, if you can select boot from `/dev/sdb`, it should work. -- **Warning: The whole partition table will be overwritten and you will lose whatever is stored in other partitions.**

Comment: So if I clone it to /dev/sdb, it will show Manjaro in the boot menu?

Comment: I don't know what boot menu you are talking about. Is it the boot menu of Windows or MacOS? -- When you want to boot from an external drive (or otherwise 'extra' drive), there is often a hotkey to press repeatedly directly at boot or reboot. -- I have a Dell Latitude, but a slightly different model than yours, and I use the hotkey `F12` to get a boot menu, where I can select which drive to boot from. I am almost sure that it will work for you too. Good luck :-)

Comment: I just have two drives in my computer, a solid state drive and a hard drive, it's not an external hard drive. I'll try to use F12 though and force it to use my other drive, thanks.

Comment: Hey @sododus, I'm typing to you on my Manjaro installation. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations, @Samuel, I'm glad that it is working for you now :-)